# having trouble to make the layout of a dialog box

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to make a `Dialog` box for simple signup page like this [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3e266hqsz8kkjnb/629px-Do-a-Presentation-in-Class-Step-2.jpg?dl=0) 
but I can't figure out how can I do this. I am basically struggling to make the cross icon to the right corner of the `Dialog` box.

Is there any library to make this?

Comment: Try searching custom dialogs in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Dialog exitBayDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        exitBayDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        exitBayDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        exitBayDialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
        final EditText etSearch = (EditText) exitBayDialog.findViewById(R.id.etVehicleNumber);
        exitBayDialog.show();
```